# Android app only updating location when other apps using location on Marshmallow

Tags: android, gps, location, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

So I have an app that works flawlessly on many devices. The problem is on one specific phone with Android 6.

The location for our app only works when another app uses the GPS. 
For example, starting our app, the GPS icon starts as if the GPS was active but location updates on the app do not appear or refresh. Then, we start Google Maps and only then locations on our app start getting refreshed. As soon as we close Google Maps, our locations stop being received.

**I actually tested the app on another phone with Android 6 with no problems.**

I think there might be some kind of issue with Google Play Services or with the new the permissions schema. Or maybe with BroadcastReceiver receiving the position updates.

**Key information:**

- Our app es compiled for SDK 22 with Google API.
- Google Play Services version on the phone with the issue is 8.4.92
- The app uses this version of play services:

  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.+'`
- All permissions are activated for our app on that phone.
- The phone with the problem was working fine before it got updated to Android 6.0
- We tested on another device with Android 6.0 and had no issues.
- The phone is in a client in another continent so we don't have access to debugging or logs. No errors occur though because we would receive those on Fabric.io.
- We use a Broadcast to dispatch new positions to a service and an activity so the problem might be there.

Im running out of options and tests.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

The problem is that on that version of Android, getSpeed from Location is always 0.0, unless another app is using the location, then we get updates with the speed included.

This really sounds like a bug. Why would legacy apps not get the speed in the location? Assuming its because we use API 22.

On a side note, we use speed to filter out positions and stop updating location when the phone is standing still. Thats why we did not see location updates.

I guess we will have to calculate our own speed.

Comment: Well the key information which phone is missing.

Comment: Check my EDIT, Location.getSpeed is always 0.0 and we filter out positions when standing still.